# Print a yaml file to a pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, yaml

Does anyone know of a way to print a nicely-formatted yaml file to a PDF in R? I'm using the `yaml` package to load the yaml file, and was wondering what the best way was to turn the keys and values into a nicely-formatted table to be printed to a PDF.

Here is what I have so far, but it's producing a single column whose entries have vectors of NA values:

```
print_inputs = function(inputs_yaml) {
  pdf(file='inputs_page.pdf', onefile=TRUE)
  mytheme = ttheme_default(
    core=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.05)),
    rowhead=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0)),
    base_size = 5,
    base_colour = "black",
    base_family = "",
    parse = FALSE,
    padding = unit(c(4, 4), "mm"))

  mat = create_empty_table(0,2)
  for (name in names(inputs_yaml)) {
    value = unlist(inputs_yaml[[name]])
    mat = rbind(mat, c(name, value))
  }

  mat = array_split(mat, 25)
  for (m in mat) { grid.table(mat, theme=mytheme); grid.newpage(); }
  dev.off()
}

create_empty_table <- function(num_rows, num_cols) {
  frame <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_cols))
  return(frame)
}
array_split <- function(data, number_of_chunks) {
  rowIdx <- seq_len(nrow(data))    
  lapply(split(rowIdx, cut(rowIdx, pretty(rowIdx, number_of_chunks))), function(x) data[x, ])
}

yaml_file = yaml.load_file('~/Downloads/inputs__towrite.yaml')
print_inputs(yaml_file)
```

Comment: I don't think there exists an out-of-the-box solution, because YAML allows for nested structures that can't be easily translated into a flat key-value table. If your YAML file has a simple key-value structure why not just read-in the YAML file, convert to a `data.frame`, and pretty-print the `data.frame` using `knitr::kable` or `stargazer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution (basically just calling toString on the values in the yaml file):

```
print_inputs <- function(inputs_yaml) {
  pdf(file='inputs_page.pdf', onefile=TRUE, height=15)

  inputs_theme = ttheme_default(
    core=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.05)),
    rowhead=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0)),
    base_size = 5,
    base_colour = "black",
    base_family = "",
    parse = FALSE,
    padding = unit(c(4, 2), "mm"))

  mat = matrix(ncol=2)
  for (name in names(inputs_yaml)) {
    value = unlist(inputs_yaml[[name]])
    value = gsub(',', '\n', toString(value))
    value = gsub('File\n', '', value)
    mat = rbind(mat, c(toString(name), value))
  }
  grid.table(mat, theme=inputs_theme)
  dev.off()
}
```